# How can I solve this issue of non working audio-player in Flutter

Tags: flutter, audio-player

I am facing a problem with getting the audio-player to work in Flutter.

My simple app consists of a bunch of keys with different colors, and each one of them is supposed to play some audio file whenever clicked *(The audio files are local and bundled with the app inside an **assets** folder which is at the same level as the lib folder, and also the audio files have an extension of .wav)*.

I am using the **audioplayers 2.0.0** library and defining an instance of the AudioPlayer and storing it in a variable, then calling the AudioPlayer with the method play and because my audios are local, I am wrapping my audio file inside AssetSource().

**But,**
whenever I click any of the keys nothing get played and there is this message in the console (This time when clicking the first key):

```
E/flutter ( 5043): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] 
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider) 
E/flutter ( 5043): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:294:7) E/flutter ( 5043): <asynchronous suspension> 
E/flutter ( 5043): #1      getTemporaryDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:55:24) 
E/flutter ( 5043): <asynchronous suspension> 
E/flutter ( 5043): #2      AudioCache.fetchToMemory (package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:78:27) 
E/flutter ( 5043): <asynchronous suspension> 
E/flutter ( 5043): #3      AudioCache.load (package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:101:31) 
E/flutter ( 5043): <asynchronous suspension> 
E/flutter ( 5043): #4      AudioPlayer.setSourceAsset (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:249:17) 
E/flutter ( 5043): <asynchronous suspension> 
E/flutter ( 5043): #5      AudioPlayer.play (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:131:5) 
E/flutter ( 5043): <asynchronous suspension> 
E/flutter ( 5043):
```

Here is my code in the main file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget buildKey(int noteToPlay, Color keyColor) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: keyColor,
        child: TextButton(
          child: Text('This is the button #$noteToPlay',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () async{
            final player = AudioPlayer();
            player.play(AssetSource('assets_note$noteToPlay.wav'));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  buildKey(1, Colors.red),
                  buildKey(2, Colors.orange),
                  buildKey(3, Colors.yellow),
                  buildKey(4, Colors.green),
                  buildKey(5, Colors.teal),
                  buildKey(6, Colors.blue),
                  buildKey(7, Colors.purple),
                ]
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I read about the audioplayers library and tried to figure out the problem, but came to no conclusions, hope you can help me

Comment: please format the error message same way as code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant part is that you are receiving a `MissingPluginException`, which means that flutter cannot find a package implementation. Make sure that you included all the packages you rely on in your pubspec.yaml file.

Afterwards, delete your app from the device/simulator and reinstall again. This will load all the plugin-channels to native code

Comment: I already have included the packages in the pubspec.yaml, but it didn't work then. I tried removing the device and opening it again as you said **and it did work**. Thanks a lot.